# How to adjust logo with CSS Viewer in QGIS Cloud Pro

Tags: css, qgis-cloud

I am new to creating web maps and am using QGIS Cloud Pro. I uploaded our company logo onto the web map, but most of the logo is cut off. Using the Viewer tool and CSS there I have tried to adjust it so that all of it shows. I can adjust most other things on the web map using CSS with trial and error, but have not figured out how to get our whole logo to show.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. Through the inspector on google chrome, I was able to make the correct changes there and copy and paste into the QGIS Cloud viewer.

Comment: What were the changes needed?